# How to scrape website which is dynamically rendered with filters?

Tags: node.js, axios, cheerio

Website renders products after filters are applied but source code remains same. I want to scrape products which are present on the screen. I am using cheerio and axios in node.js but cheerio gets only the source code body which is not what I require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think easiest way to do it would be to take a look into network tab. My suspicion is that website is dynamicly loading this data fro some sort of API, so you actually need to scrape incoming data from that API and not website itself.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. That's what the case was here. Thank you once again!!! :)